# Display the first object in useState() array with data pulled from a database (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-effect, use-state

I am pulling a list of people from a database. When I map the array into many different components it works and the data gets displayed correctly. But when i want to access an individual element of the list `trainer[0].id` it says that the data does not exist. My guess is that the database isn't ready but how can I await that?
Here is my code:

```js
export default function TrainerInfo() {

    const [trainer, setTrainer] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const trainerCollectionRef = collection(database, "trainer");

        const getTrainer = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(trainerCollectionRef);
            setTrainer(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
        };

        getTrainer();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="cms-stats">
            <TrainerSelection>
                {trainer.map(t => <Trainer id={t.id} key={t.id}>{t.name}</Trainer>)}
                // works
            </TrainerSelection>
            <Info id={trainer[0].id} name={trainer[0].name} status={trainer[0].status} image={trainer[0].image} key={trainer[0].id}/>
            // does not work
        </div>
    )
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is is that your code renders the component before the data is ready. You first need to check if the data is ready in your render process before you render elements where data access is needed.

```
            <TrainerSelection>
                {trainer.map(t => <Trainer id={t.id} key={t.id}>{t.name}</Trainer>)}
                // works
            </TrainerSelection>
            { trainer.length > 0 && 
                <Info id={trainer[0].id} name={trainer[0].name} status={trainer[0].status} image={trainer[0].image} key={trainer[0].id}/>
            }
```

With this code react will first check if trainer is true (in this case if the array is not empty in js an empty array is false). If the array is empty js will skip the render check, because javascript evaluates statements lazely, you can read more about it [here](https://aashni.me/blog/lazy-evaluations-and-short-circuit-logic-in-javascript/).

Else the `Info` component will render.

In this case the `TrainerSelection` component doesn't throw an error, because you used the `map` method. So when the array is empty at the first render nothing will render, but when the state is updated the component is rerendered and you don't notice the difference.

This is one way to dit it but you could also use another `useState` variable to track if the data can be displayed.

EDIT: changed `{ trainer && ...` to `{ trainer.length > 0 && ..`. Not sure why it would matter in this case but it solved the issue.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense but I get the error that the property id is undefined `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

Comment: That doesn't mean the `id` property is undefined but the object you are reading `id` from. So in this case that means `trainer[0]` is undefined.

Comment: Yes but how can I fix this?

Comment: By checking if the `trainer` array is not empty during rendering like I explained in my answer.

Comment: But I checked it with trainer && ... like you explained. First it works but when I refresh the page I get the error in the console and react stops working

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error when you refresh the page? Also are you sure this is where the error occured and not also somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246692/discussion-between-ahamfm-and-casper-kuethe).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Info id={trainer[0].id} name={trainer[0].name} status={trainer[0].status} image={trainer[0].image} key={trainer[0].id}/>
```

There is no map function for this line.

Keep this in a map function as you have done just above and it should work